# Initialise session variable before file loading

Tags: php, ajax, session

This is a little part of code existing in my **login.php** file which is a form (username-password) for logging into my system:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"check_read_status.php"
      });
 </script>
<?php
    include "index.php";
    exit;
?>
```

whereas code of check_read_status.php has as follows:

```
<?php  
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{
  $db=new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','apeirosto');         
  if (!($db->connect_errno)) 
  {
     $usermail=$_SESSION['valid_user'];
     $query="SELECT * FROM INBOX WHERE receiver='$usermail' AND status_read=0";
     $result=$db->query($query);
     if ($result->num_rows>=1)
       $_SESSION['unread_messages']=1;
     else
       $_SESSION['unread_messages']=0;    
  }
}
?>
```

My problem is I want to pass session variable ***$_SESSION['unread_messages']*** to index.php which (*index.php*) will create the new DOM since the HTML part of login.php file won't be executed (because of **exit** command). However, index.php does not get informed immediately about the value of the above session variable because of the asynchronous character of AJAX. I've tried a lot but I did not succeed to find a way of deferring the execution of **include "index.php";**. Do you have any good idea?

Thank you

Comment: Any session variable would be immediately available to index.php because it has access to the session. As for deferring, have you looked up JavaScript deferred's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is PHP code finishes execution before Javascript code execution begins. The solution is not to use AJAX and embed the code of check_read_status.php inside login.php. As simple as that!!